# Troubles with Flex/Bison

Tags: grammar, bison, flex-lexer

I try set up grammar using flex/bison by next pattern:

```
DATA: 1,2,3,4,5 PROGRAM: add,mult,div,read
```

This input must be transfered into

```
4 add mult div read 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

Where: 4 is a number of commands after "PROGRAM"
and 5 is a number of data after "DATA".
At the moment I have next code.

In asm.y (bison):

```
%{
 #include<stdio.h>

 int comm[100];
 int data[100];
 int ncomm=0;
 int ndata=0;
%}

%token NUMBER

%%

PROGR:"DATA: "INPUT" PROGRAM: "COMMANDS
;

COMMANDS: 
| INSTR","COMMANDS
;

| NUMBER","INPUT {data[ndata]=$1; ndata++;}
;

INSTR:NUMBER {comm[ncomm]=$1; ncomm++;}
|"add" {comm[ncomm]=-10000; ncomm++;}
|"mult" {comm[ncomm]=-10001; ncomm++;}
|"div" {comm[ncomm]=-10002; ncomm++;}
|"minus" {comm[ncomm]=-10003; ncomm++;}
//and so on
;

%%
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

 yyparse();

 printf("\n%d ",ncomm);
 int i;
 for(i=0; i<ncomm; i++)
 {
  printf("%d ",comm[i]);
 }
 printf("%d ",ndata);
 for(i=0; i<ndata; i++)
 {
  printf("%d ",data[i]);
 }

}

yyerror(char* s)
{
 printf("error: %s\n",s);
}
```

And in asm.l (flex):

```
%{
 #include "asm.tab.h"
%}

%%

[0-9]+ {return NUMBER;}

%%
```

So, after all, program doesn't print right data, but, for example

For

```
DATA: PROGRAM: add
```

It prints

```
DATA: PROGRAM: add
```

and await for next input.

On the other hand, for

```
DATA: 5 PROGRAM: add
```

It prints

```
DATA: error: syntax error

0 0
```

And I have no idea what I do wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have a lot of work to do.  When you say that it works for `DATA: PROGRAM: add`, well, it does not: you have been bitten by a "feature" for Lex: unrecognized characters are printed on the standard output.

So:

- tell Flex you don't want unknown characters to pass-through.

  ```
  %option nodefault
  ```
- you need to teach Bison that tokens such as `"DATA:"` will be used.  Something like:

  ```
  %token ADD "add"
  %token DATA "DATA:"
  ```

  Then be sure to exactly `"DATA:"` or `DATA` in the rest of the file, don't use `"DATA: "` for instance.
- you need your scanner/lexer to recognize all the tokens you need: not just numbers, but also keywords (or identifiers) such as `add`, `mult`, etc. Something like:

  ```
  "+"  return ADD;
  ```

  but also `"DATA:"`.

  ```
  "DATA:" return DATA;
  ```
- Make sure to tell your parser generator that a `NUMBER` has a value:

  ```
  %token <int> NUMBER
  ```
- and tell you scanner to compute it.

You have much to learn.  Before trying to do all this, be sure to try the basic [examples from Bison's documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Examples.html#Examples), and to perfectly understand them.

Comment: @Gcinbax Well, then you could click on my answer to accept it.